# Calculate size difference between two Exchange mailboxes

Tags: powershell, exchange-2013

I can get the size of a mailbox using `Get-MailboxStatistics`. How do I find the difference between two mailbox sizes using Powershell?

I tried:

```
(Get-MailboxStatistics FordPrefect).totalitemsize - (Get-MailboxStatistics ArthurDent).totalitemsize
```

which results in the error:

> Method invocation failed because
>   [System.ManagementAutomation.PSObject] doesn't contain method named
>   'op_Subtraction'

which is kinda correct as the `totalitemsize` object does not have the subtraction method/member. How do I then proceed further with the operation?

Comment: If you want to get all users information, you could use the following command to export to a csv file:
`Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Get-MailboxStatistics | ft DisplayName,TotalItemSize | out-file c:\user.csv`

Answer (score 3):

TotalItemSize is not a number, the property has two members:

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>(Get-MailboxStatistics administrator).totalitemsize

IsUnlimited Value
----------- -----
      False 690.4 KB (706,925 bytes)
```

This should work:

```
(Get-MailboxStatistics FordPrefect).totalitemsize.Value - (Get-MailboxStatistics ArthurDent).totalitemsize.Value
```

Comment: Tried the Value property, gives me the same error as that too doesn't support the `subtraction` operation

Comment: What is the version of Exchange you are working with?

Comment: Oh, it's Exchange 2013 I see now. My answer is based on Exchange 2016. I do not have 2013 available here. In 2010 things are different. I'll test it in that version, maybe 2013 is the same as 2010 in this matter.

Comment: If you run your script (implicit) remotely that is probably the cause of your problems. Have a look at this thread:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156368/exchange-2010-totalitemsize-value-tobytes-always-empty

Comment: Thanks, I thought there was a better way than to processing as a string using `TrimEnd`

Comment: Maybe you could try to export the result to a csv file, and manually compare the size.